# Google Apps Scripts - How to replace a file?

Tags: file, pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to replace a PDF file in a Google Drive Folder using a script. Since GAS does not provide a method for adding revisions (versions), I'm trying to replace the content of the file, but all I get is a blank PDF.

I can't use the DriveApp.File class since our Admin has disabled the new API, so I have to use DocsList.File instead.

- **Input:**

  - OldFile.pdf (8 pages)
  - NewFile.pdf (20 pages)
- **Output expected:**

  - OldFile.pdf with the same content as NewFile.pdf
- **Real Output:**

  - OldFile.pdf with 20 empty pages.

**Process:**

```
var old = DocsList.getFileById("####");
var new = DocsList.getFileById("####");
old.replace(new.getContentAsString());
```

Any ideas, please?
Thanks a lot in advance.

PS.: I also tried calling old.clear() first, but I'd say the problem lies on the getContentAsString method.

Comment: `getContentAsString()` smells like doing some decoding according to some character encoding, e.g. UTF-8, which would effectively break some PDF content, e.g. page content streams which normally are compressed and, therefore, very sensitive to changes.

Comment: Do you need to keep the same doc ID as a requirement?  If not , you could simply delete and rename...

Comment: Yes, I need the same ID, because it is linked from a web.

Comment: You could use the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/24226885/1058108. Basically, you use the Drive.Files.update(file, fileId, updatedBlob) API that is available if you activate it through Resources > Advanced Google Services >  Drive API > ON

Answer (score 8):

The [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) can be used to replace the content of an existing PDF file in Google Drive.  This answer also includes an example of how to update  a PDF file in a shared Drive.

```
function overwriteFile(blobOfNewContent,currentFileID) {
  var currentFile;
  
  currentFile = DriveApp.getFileById(currentFileID);    
  
  if (currentFile) {//If there is a truthy value for the current file
    Drive.Files.update({
      title: currentFile.getName(), mimeType: currentFile.getMimeType()
    }, currentFile.getId(), blobOfNewContent);
  }
}
```

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update

An example of using with a shared Drive:

```
Drive.Files.update({ title: currentFile.getName(), mimeType: 
  currentFile.getMimeType() }, currentFile.getId(), blobOfNewContent, 
  {supportsTeamDrives: true});
```

Comment: In case of team drive your call will be like `Drive.Files.update({
      title: currentFile.getName(), mimeType: currentFile.getMimeType()
    }, currentFile.getId(), blobOfNewContent,{supportsTeamDrives: true});`

Comment: It looks like the line that writes the new content can be as simple as `Drive.Files.update({}, currentFileID, blobOfNewContent)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get it as a **blob** datatype instead.

Comment: I also tried to, but the result is the same.
old.replace(new.getBlob().getDataAsString());
It produces the same result, an unreadable pdf.

Comment: dont convert it to string. there are methods to create a file from a blob.

Comment: I know. I can create a File from blob, and that works perfect.
My problem is that I need to overwrite the contents of a file, in order to keep its ID.

Comment: then its not possible to do what you want from the native apps script apis. You need to use the drive API (which is blocked for you) to upload a new revision of the file, plus you have to figure out how to edit that revision before (not with getDataAsString :)