# Overwrite an Image File with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Can I overwrite an image file with Google Apps Script?  I've tried:

```
file.setContent(newBlobImage);
file.replace(newBlobImage);
```

Neither of those work.  `.setContent()` will delete whatever data was in the file, and it looks like maybe it just writes the variable name as text, or something like that.  I'm assuming that both `.setContent()` and `.replace()` are meant for text documents, and maybe that's why they don't work.

If it were a text file, or a spreadsheet, I might be able to clear it, then append new content.

I can trash the file, then create a new one, but I'd rather not if there is some other way.

If I write a file with the same name, it won't overwrite the existing file, it creates a another file with the same name.

The only way I've been able to trash the file is with `DocsList` and the only success I've had with creating an image file is with `DriveApp`.  So I have to trash the file with `DocsList`, then create another file with `DriveApp`.

Well, I've figured out how to delete the file without sending it to the trash, so I won't need to clean out the trash later.  The `Google Drive SDK` inside of Apps Script has a `remove` method that didn't send the file to trash, it's just gone.

```
var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('3Bg2dKau456ySkhNBWB98W5sSTM');

thisFile = myFolder.getFilesByName(myFileName);

while (thisFile.hasNext()) {
  var eachFile = thisFile.next();
  var idToDLET = eachFile.getId();
  Logger.log('idToDLET: ' + idToDLET);

  var rtrnFromDLET = Drive.Files.remove(idToDLET);
};
```

So, I'm combining the `DriveApp` service and the `DriveAPI` to delete the file without sending it to the trash.  The `DriveAPI` .remove needs the file ID, but I don't have the file ID, so the file gets looked up by name, then the file ID is retrieved, then the ID is used to delete the file.  So, if I can't find a way to overwrite the file, I can at least delete the old file without it going to the trash.

I just noticed that the `DriveAPI` service has a `Patch` and an `Update` option.

```
.patch(resource, fileId, optionalArgs)
```

[Google Documentation Patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch)  Updates file metadata.

The `resource` arg is probably the metadata.  The `fileId` is self explanatory.  I'm guessing that the `optionalArgs` are parameters that follow the HTTP Request Patch semantics?  I don't know.

It looks like both Patch and Update will update data.  Update is a `PUT` request that will

> clears previously set data if you don't supply optional parameters.

According to the documentation.  So it's safer to use a Patch request because any parameters that are missing are simply ignored.  I haven't tried it yet, but maybe this is the answer.

I'm getting an error with `Patch`, so I'll try `Update`:

```
.update(resource, fileId, mediaData)
```

That has a arg for mediaData in the form of a blob.  And I think that is what I need.  But I'm not sure what the `resource` parameter needs.  So I'm stuck there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An image file can be overwritten with Google Apps Script and the DriveAPI using the `update()` method:

```
.update(File resource, String fileId, Blob mediaData)
```

Where `file resource` is:

```
var myFileName = 'fileName' + '.jpg';

var file = {
  title: myFileName,
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
};
```

I'm getting the file ID with the DriveApp service, and the Blob is what was uploaded by the user.

In order to use `DriveAPI`, you need to add it through the `Resources`, `Advanced Google Services` menu.  Set the `Drive API` to **ON**.

```
var allFilesByName,file,myFolder,myVar,theFileID,thisFile;
   //Define var names without assigning a value

file = {
  title: myFileName,
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
};

myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID');

allFilesByName = myFolder.getFilesByName(myFileName);

while (allFilesByName.hasNext()) {
  thisFile = allFilesByName.next();
  theFileID = thisFile.getId();
  //Logger.log('theFileID: ' + theFileID);
  
  myVar = Drive.Files.update(file, theFileID, uploadedBlob);
};
```

Comment: May I know where you find the API parameters description for Drive.Files.update in Google developers documentation ? Couldn't find it. Because i had inverted the first two parameters, and you helped me to solve my own issue..

Comment: The Drive API reference is located at this link:  [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)  The syntax is different for the REST API in the reference, and Apps Script.  But Apps Script gives syntax in the auto complete.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't think about autocomplete. of course !

Comment: Updating here as well for helping others. In case of team drive add  `supportsTeamDrives` argument at last. Like this `Drive.Files.update({
      title: currentFile.getName(), mimeType: currentFile.getMimeType()
    }, currentFile.getId(), blobOfNewContent,{supportsTeamDrives: true});`

Comment: Thanks @DarpanSanghavi for the trick about supportsTeamDrives, Drive API was returning an error without this attribute!

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for this track !

This allowed me to find a solution to my problem : **move a bound form after copying and moved his spreadsheet**.

The Drive app advanced service must be activated in the "Resource Script Editor" to run this script.

```
function spreadsheetCopy() {
  // Below is the file to be copied with a bound form.
  var fileToCopy = DriveApp.getFileById("file_key"); // key is fileId
  var saveFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder_key"); // key is folderId
  var currentFolder = "";
  ( fileToCopy.getParents().next() ) ? currentFolder = fileToCopy.getParents().next() : currentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();  
  Logger.log(currentFolder)
  var copyFile = fileToCopy.makeCopy(saveFolder),
      copyName = copyFile.getName(); 
  Utilities.sleep(30000);
 moveFormCopy(currentFolder, saveFolder, copyName);
}

function moveFormCopy(currentFolder, saveFolder, copyName) {  
  var formsInFolder = currentFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
  var form, copyForm, copyFormMimeType, copyFormName, copyFormId;
  while ( formsInFolder.hasNext() ) {
    form = formsInFolder.next();
    if ( copyName === form.getName() ) {
      copyForm = form;
      copyFormMimeType = copyForm.getMimeType();
      copyFormName = copyForm.getName();
      copyFormId = copyForm.getId();
      break;
    }
  };  
  var resource = {title: copyName, mimeType: copyFormMimeType};
  Drive.Files.patch(resource, copyFormId, {addParents: saveFolder.getId(), removeParents: currentFolder.getId()})
}
```