# I need to overwrite an existing Google Sheets file with an attached Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drive

I have a Google Sheets file with an attached Script. The script does a number of things, one is it makes a clone of it self using makeCopy. This portion works. Now I want to be able to keep the same cloned Google file name and same Google file ID and just update the content which includes a Spreadsheet and the associated Google script.

```
if (!fileFound){
  var file = masterSSFile.makeCopy(reportFileName, RepFolder);
} else {
  oldFile.setContent(masterSSFile.getBlob());        
}
```

When I use makeCopy with the same file name it creates a second file with the same name but with a different file ID.
The else portion fails because .setContent argument seems to just accept text.  The result is the word "Blob" in the oldFile, everything else is gone.

I have other scripts that update the contents of a existing spreadsheet by overriding the contents of the various sheets, but I also want the associated script to also be included in the updated file keeping the same file ID.

Comment: I know that it's possible to update the contents of a ***Stand Alone*** Apps Script file with code.  But I don't think it's possible to update an existing Apps Script file bound to a spreadsheet.  With an Add-on, the document with the Add-on automatically gets the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I found this....

[Overwrite an Image File with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225748/overwrite-an-image-file-with-google-apps-script)

and tried using

```
var masterSpreadsheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var masterSpreadsheetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(masterSpreadsheetID);
var oldFileID = oldFile.getId();
var oldFileName = oldFile.getName();
var newBlob = masterSpreadsheetFile.getBlob();
var file = {
  title: oldFileName,
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
  };
var f = Drive.Files.update(file, oldFileID, newBlob);
```

I get error: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. " on this line: "Drive.Files.update(file, oldFileID, newBlob);"

After reading this:
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/495

it looks like Drive.Files.update(), does not support bound scripts.

Comment: what you are trying to do is just not possible. You can actually overwrite a spreadsheet content  including format and formulas but this doesn't include the attached script. The only way to keep the script is to copy the file (using drive API) but then the ID will be different.

Comment: Thanks,  That is what I understand now, and again thanks for taking the time to respond.  I figured out a way to live with having the ID change every time the file is updated using .makeCopy.